# how is JNDI used in RMI and JMS?

Tags: java, jms, jndi, rmi

I would like to know how JMS and RMI uses JNDI ,i would also appreciate any snippets of code explaining it .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) provides a standard way of accessing naming and directory services

**Example Obtaining the initial JNDI context:**

```
 import javax.naming.*;
 private static InitialContext ctx = null;
  ...
  public static InitialContext getInitialContext( ) throws NamingException {
   if (ctx == null) {
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable( );
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
        "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, 
        "t3://myserver:8001");
    ctx = new InitialContext(env);
   }
 return ctx;
 }
```

See [Chapter 4. Using JNDI and RMI](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/weblogic-the-definitive/059600432X/ch04.html) of *WebLogic: The Definitive Guide* for more details.